# How to Fix this error Android Studio gradle sync error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

plz help me, what is problem in this error.

```
Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    file:/Users/maneesha/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/28.0.0/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

Comment: as it says.. "Please install the Android Support Repository from the SDK manager"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to your SDK Manager. You can get there in two ways.

**First Option**

In the toolbar select --> Tools --> SDK Manager.

[image]

**Second Option**

Go directly to SDK Manager in the top right of your Android Studio.

[image]

**Finally**

In both ways you will end up in the SDK Manager page.

- Select SDK Tools.
- Download or update the Android Support Repository.

You just have to select it and click on Apply.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The support library is no longer delivered via SDK Manager.

> #### Adding Support Libraries
>
> [...]
>
> To add a Support Library to your application project:
>
> 1. Include Google's Maven repository in your top-level `build.gradle` file.
>
>    ```
>    allprojects {
>        repositories {
>            google()
>
>            // If you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1, you must
>            // instead use:
>            //
>            // maven {
>            //     url 'https://maven.google.com'
>            // }
>        }
>    }
>    ```

Source: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup

Answer (score -1):

Go to tools->and select SDK manager.
This option will open SDK manager. Select the SDK platform and click on checkbox for android pie and select apply and Ok
This will download the selected repository.
Hope it helps.